# How to write a regex for [mm:ss.SS] text <mm:ss.SSS> text

Tags: regex

How can I write a regex to extract the time from something like the below:

Example:

```
[00:16.150]Why <00:16.600>do you <00:16.800>look <00:17.150>so <00:17.600>glum?
```

Comment: i'm developing a karaoke application bro...

Answer (score 0):

`\[\d{2}:\d{2}\.\d{3}\](?:.*?<\d{2}:\d{2}\.\d{3}>)*.*`
should match (if I haven't made a mistake), but I don't know what you want to do with the matched text.

Comment: i'm developing a karaoke application bro, thx for your answered :)